# How to manage global variable in nested function

Tags: javascript, node.js, napajs

I have simple requirement, I need `abc` available  in `hello` function but getting `undefined` I know below code giving me `undefined` and It should give

```js
function hello(){
 console.log("printing abc ",abc);
}

function test(){
 var abc  = "hello";
 hello();
}
```

but is anything there that I can make `abc` available in `hello` function without passing manually, I am doing this for `napajs` `execute` function where i have to call nested function and I do not want to pass variable in hierarchy .

Comment: You can declare the variable globally like before `hello()` and then you can use this variable in any function or nested function.

Comment: I can't I have to declare in function.

Comment: Not sure if I get this correctly. Anyhow, I would say that you still need to rely on lexical scoping to reference free variables from within a function. That is, you need some environment; not necessarily the global environment, but _some_ environment nonetheless.

Comment: Javascript gives you an assortment of ways to get `abc` into hello. You can pass it into `hello` with `hello(abc)` and then define `hello` to take a parameter. You can assign it to a variable in a scope shared by both. etc... But if your requirement is to declare it in `test()` and have it just be available in `hello()`…that's not going to happen.  You should explain *why* the normal ways of passing data won't work, otherwise ti seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer

```js
function hello(){
    console.log("printing abc", this.abc);
}

function test(){
    this.abc  = "hello";
    hello();
}

test();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this approach be troublesome in strict mode, given that `this` would be `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

Try using let instead of var.
Not sure of the result, but technically let will be block scoped

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict'

function hello(){

  console.log('---------1-------------')

  console.log("printing abc ",abc);

 }

 function test(){
   console.log('--------------2-----------')

  abc  = "hello";

  hello();

 }

 global.abc ='anjj';

 var a = test();
```

//please try this way